# Converting CURL Command to Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, curl

I'm struggling with converting a working CURL command over to PowerShell so I can utilize Invoke-RestMethod.

1. The CURL command seems to work fine.
2. I can use Invoke-RestMethod to hit other endpoint on the remote API just fine
3. I feel like something is wrong in the way I'm formatting the "organizationIds" number array, but I can't seem to figure it out (of course, it could be something else entirely too)

This is an example of my working CURL command:

```
curl.exe "https://cert-manager.com/api/report/v1/ssl-certificates" -i -X POST -H "customerUri: InCommon" -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8" -H "login: MyUserNameInfoGoesHere" -H "password: MyPasswordInfoGoesHere" -d "{\"from\":\"2019-08-05T00:00:00.000Z\",\"to\":\"2019-11-03T00:00:00.000Z\",\"organizationIds\":[3637,574,570],\"certificateStatus\":0,\"certificateDateAttribute\":3,\"certificateRequestSource\":0}"
```

And this is what I've been fiddling with in PowerShell:

```
[string]$from = "2019-08-05T00:00:00.000Z";
[string]$to = "2019-11-03T00:00:00.000Z";
$organizationIds = @(3637, 574, 570);
[int]$certificateStatus = 0;
[int]$certificateDateAttribute = 3;
[int]$certificateRequestSource = 0;   
[PsObject]$data = @(
    @{
        from                     = $from
        to                       = $to
        organizationIds          = $organizationIds
        certificateStatus        = $certificateStatus
        certificateDateAttribute = $certificateDateAttribute
        certificateRequestSource = $certificateRequestSource
    }
)
$jsonData = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $data;
[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String], [String]]]$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]";
Set-StandardHeaderConfig -Headers $headers;
[string]$method = "POST";
$certificateReport = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method $method -Body $jsonData;
```

Oh, and here is my "Set-StandardHeaderConfig" PowerShell function (this works fine for my other calls):

```
Function Set-StandardHeaderConfig {
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String], [String]]]$headers
)
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$headers.Add("login", MyUserNameInfoGoesHere);
$headers.Add("password", MyPasswordInfoGoesHere);
$headers.Add("customerUri", "InCommon");
```

Can anyone help nudge me in the right direction for a fix to this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I may see the problem.  In running your code and analyzing the `$jsonData` variable, it looks like there is additional `value` and `Count` properties being added to the object.

I found this by comparing the JSON body your curl command is sending to the JSON produced by `$jsonData = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $data;`

[image]

Try changing

```
$jsonData = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $data;
```

to

```
$jsonData = $data | ConvertTo-Json
```

That removed those extra properties for me.

Comment: When I make that change, my data looks more like it does in CURL, but I still get an error: Invoke-RestMethod : {"code":-14,"description":"Wrong method or empty parameter supplied"}